# CSS3 Transition and Transform

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want my Simple responsive bootstrap's thumbnails [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Norhan/pv6hd9x6/embedded/result/) to **move smoothly** during  **resizing** the browser's window .

So any way to do that with `CSS3` **transition** and **transform** ?
I don't want using any `jQuery` plugins . It just a simple Gallery

**HTML**

```
<div class=" container">
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="thumbnails ">
            <li class="col-md-3     ">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="http://conflictbase.com/">

                    <img src="http://placehold.it/300" alt="" class="img-responsive" />

                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="col-md-3    ">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="http://conflictbase.com/">

                    <img src="http://placehold.it/300" alt="" class="img-responsive" />

                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="col-md-3    ">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="http://conflictbase.com/">

                    <img src="http://placehold.it/300" alt="" class="img-responsive" />

                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="col-md-3   ">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="http://conflictbase.com/">

                    <img src="http://placehold.it/300" alt="" class="img-responsive" />

                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="col-md-3    ">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="http://conflictbase.com/">

                    <img src="http://placehold.it/300" alt="" class="img-responsive" />

                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="col-md-3   ">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="http://conflictbase.com/">

                    <img src="http://placehold.it/300" alt="" class="img-responsive" />

                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="col-md-3   ">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="http://conflictbase.com/">

                    <img src="http://placehold.it/300" alt="" class="img-responsive" />

                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="col-md-3    ">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="http://conflictbase.com/">

                    <img src="http://placehold.it/300" alt="" class="img-responsive" />

                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    ul.thumbnails li{
    display: inline-block;
   }
   .thumbnail{
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.thumbnail img{
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
}
body{
    margin:30px 0px;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Norhan** Hi there.

To have it **Transition** you first need to give it some points to transition between... like adding classes to this.
To go from `col-lg-3` to `col-md-4` to `col-sm-6` and so on.

Here is a working **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scntLwp6/)** to view.

[image: css transition animation]

**Added to this post**
To make it clear for other people reading this post.

You can also use the **all** and **width** for this css transition.
like this...

```
.transition-width { 
    transition: all 2s ease-out; 
    webkit-transition: all 2s ease-out; 
}
```

Or using **width**

```
.transition-width { 
    transition: width 2s ease-out; 
    webkit-transition: width 2s ease-out; 
}
```

Here is a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scntLwp6/1/)** using **all** as another option.

Comment: Yes exactly as i want :) ..... Thanks alot
You make me know why it was not give me same effect

Comment: Hi, you are welcome. just need to give the transition a place to work between.

Comment: Actually i needed to make transition only for width ..... i made it for all .... so the effect didn't work .... Thanks again
---- My code after updating : [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pv6hd9x6/5/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 0):

You would want to add a CSS transition class to all your `li` elements and then [insert media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) for each breakpoint in your design. That should handle everything breaking down into different arrangements.

```
   ul.thumbnails li{
    display: inline-block;
    transition:all 0.5s;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for interesting 
I tried that way before but didn't get any effect there ......
Can you show me on  [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Norhan/pv6hd9x6/embedded/result/) ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pv6hd9x6/5/ -- something like this. However, if you want to see them literally rearrange, you will have to use JavaScript. This plugin is what you might be looking for: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: Thanks alot .... i found the reason that why not give me the effect .... I was give transition:all ... but the right way is transition: width ..... to give the smoothly effect moving

Comment: @Norhan, you can use **all** as well, that will work fine. It just needed somethimg to work... transition to.

Comment: Ya as i see you example ( **Thanks for it :)** ) ... it works too